# How to get dynamic object properties

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I'm receiving a Json object from a request and I would like to Iterate over its properties and do something like:

if property is equals to "EN" than get it's value.

The solutions That I saw in the web are all related with GetProperties/GetProperty methods but I tried both and none of them worked.
This should be something "simple" but I think that I'm missing something here.

```
//Deserializing the object
ExpandoObject deserializedContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(obj.ToString(), new ExpandoObjectConverter());
dynamic deserializedDynamicContent = deserializedContent;

//Tries
var value = deserializedDynamicContent.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

var value = deserializedDynamicContent.GetType().GetProperty("ES").GetValue();
```

in both cases I get zero properties.

I can only get the values if I do the code below, but this will obly me to code if a new language is added.

```
deserializedDynamicContent.EN,
deserializedDynamicContent.ES or
deserializedDynamicContent.PT
```

What Am I doing wrong here?

```
{
"EN":[{"Id":1,"Name":"One"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Two"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Tree"}],
"ES":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Uno"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Dos"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Tres"}],
"PT":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Um"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Dois"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Três"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but since [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) implements `IDictionary<string,object>` you should be able to do something like this:

```
var expando = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(yourJson);
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;

// look for a particular key...
object value;
if (dict.TryGetValue("EN", out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key exists!");
    var list = (List<dynamic>)value;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list.Select(x => "{" + x.Id + "," + x.Name + "}")));
}

// or enumerate the entire dictionary...
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    var list = (List<dynamic>)kvp.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(
        kvp.Key + ":" + string.Join(",", list.Select(x => "{" + x.Id + "," + x.Name + "}")));
}
```